# Class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10}) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am interested in knowing how to compute the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10}) $. I am confused with these class number computations.

Comment: May I ask what your background is?  How have you seen the definition of the class number of quadratic fields?

Comment: see this http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf

Comment: I can tell you this much: the class number in this case is greater than 1, since in its ring of algebraic integers you can readily find plenty of examples to disprove unique factorization, e.g., $9 = 3^2 = (7 - 2\sqrt{10})(7 + 2\sqrt{10})$.

Answer (score 3):

The link in the comments changed, so I answer.

The Minkowski bund is  $\sqrt{10}$ itself, so tge relevant prime norms are $2$ and $3$.

$2$ is ramified and gives the factorization $(2)=(2,\sqrt{10})^2$. As $|x^2-10y^2|=2$ has no solutions with $\pm2\bmod5$ a quadratic nonresidue, $(2,10)$ is not principal and thus contributes a $2$-cycle to the class group.

$3$ splits giving $(3)=(3,\sqrt{10}+1)(3,\sqrt{10}-1)$ from $x^2-10\equiv(x+1)(x-1)\bmod3$. If we multiply either of these factors by $(2,\sqrt{10})$ we get

$(2,\sqrt{10})(3,\sqrt{10}+1)=(6,3\sqrt{10},2\sqrt{10}+2,\sqrt{10}+10)$

$=(3\sqrt{10},2\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10}+10)$

$=(\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10}+10)=(\sqrt{10})$

So $(3,\sqrt{10}+1)\sim(2,\sqrt{10})^{-1}=(2,\sqrt{10})$ with $(2,\sqrt{10})$ being of order $2$, and similarly $(3,\sqrt{10}-1)\sim(2,\sqrt{10})$.

So the class group is the $2$-cycle generated by $(2,\sqrt{10})$ and the class number is $2$.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to reduce the number of unanswered questions.